# How should Azure DevOps and App Center be connected for git push hooks?

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

Our App Center 'Build on every push' is not working.  When I merge a PR in Azure DevOps and refresh App Center it shows the new commit but never triggers a build even though the build is configured to do so.  [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/802) reports the same issue, but doesn't offer any resolution.

In Azure DevOps I see two service hooks configured for App Center (both created by an ex-employee).  When I try to test those hooks, both return a 404 error from App Center.  I can find no documentation on how service hooks between Azure DevOps and App Center should be set up.

Is there some way I can disconnect the service hooks and re-create them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted App Center support using the chat button in the lower corner. They did a soft reset on the projects on their back end and the existing service hooks started working.

Not sure could I have fixed the issue without support, as I didn't try recreating the service hooks myself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way I can disconnect the service hooks and re-create them?

The answer is yes.

You could go to the **Project Settings**->**Service hook**, select the service hook for App Center. You could delete it, then create a new service hook:

[image]

If you could not delete it, please check if you have permission to delete the  service hook.

**Update:**

Since you want to create a service hook, you could configure it as follows stpes:

- Select Azure devops as service on the **Build** tab:
  [image]
- Sign in with **your Azure devops account** and select the project you want to build.
- Make sure the option `Build this branch on every push` is select:

[image]

Then, we could submit any change in that project in azure devops repo, the build in app center will be triggered. We could also check the service hook:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The document you link to is about bug tracker integration, not about git hook integration. I can delete them, but I'm unsure how to recreate them later.

Comment: @Sampo, Please check my updated answer for some more details.